# A problem while using rsync to backup my website !

Tags: web, backup, rsync

rsync -a "usernamexxx@hostxxx:/home/erogol/public_html" /website folder --times --links --recursive --hard-links -e ssh --progress --delete

I used such a command and get

ssh: connect to host ***** port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [Receiver=3.0.7]

I have this error message on terminal. I tried another port like 21 but i also does not work. Is there any other solution?

I try to backup my website also if you know any other method to backup it please tell me.

Thanks for answerers!

Comment: Not really a programming related error. I suspect bandwidth throttling (wait a few hours). Trying random ports is silly. Use the documented port, which is 22 by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server you are trying to connect to is probably not listening on port 22. Are you sure an SSH server is running on hostxxx?

try: `ssh usernamexxx@hostxxx`

and verify that you can connect to the server with SSH.

Comment: ""ssh: connect to host eren.0fees.net port 22: Connection refused""
      it gives that error and does not connect

Comment: I guess that either there is no SSH server running on the server you are connecting to, or the connection request is blocked by a firewall on the server side. Contact the administrator of the server.